# Inferring when a type holds a specific type inside a mixed array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic type that allows to infer when a specific type implements a mixed array of a specific type.

```
const one = 'one' as const;
const two = 'two' as const;
const three = 'three' as const;

type Foo = {
    id: number;
    refs: Array<{
        identity: typeof one;
    }>;
};
type Bar = {
    id: number;
    refs: Array<
        | {
                identity: typeof one;
          }
        | {
                identity: typeof two;
          }
        | {
                identity: typeof three;
          }
    >;
};
type Baz = {
    id: number;
};

type Entities = Foo | Bar | Baz;
type HasRefs<T> = T extends { refs: any[] } ? T : never;

type ImplementsThree<E extends { refs: any[] }> = E['refs'] extends (infer U)[]
    ? U extends { identity: typeof three }
        ? E
        : never
    : never;

const Bar: ImplementsThree<HasRefs<Entities>>; // Expected Bar. Instead type is Foo | Bar
```

For convenience a: [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBOCmMC8MDkDUwIYRqSUA3AFD7QxQDuIyaVImOe40JZsUAFgE7yIqouveI1zsSxKAE8ADogBiIGigDexGBpgBLACYAuGGACuAWwBG8biU0xeAMwgGAgt25YpAHjU2bu%20GCgtaQNpORA7ODB4a00AXwA%20EliSUMQAISxuWm9NXQNjc0sYjXtHGBc3T3UfDQAfGByapu0df0Dgill4cMjo6ubY-p96xuafPwCgqRCunvpipsHmkaGx3NbJjtS5nj4FmqXNROJkyS6YDIAvbKG8w1MLKxOJVJgAUU2teFwURRp6jJZAFYS4pc4ACRwACV4A4PAAVeK0eEweAADyg-h0uBUtlhZSwYCkAG0ALowWIwAD8MBR%20XgADcisQznIYABJEwyAA28BMbQg8N28A8b1RGKxOLxDgMhJJ5IStDexNQpVQ5PRmLA2JgAAotGA7JYYABVACUZKGNJN4q1OtxE3a006YQiQj4FNWmhpby9GnpTO4QwDzJZ7AumQMnJ5fIFQuEHkhEBhcI%207S%20EHiSJQACIczAAPQF95ouTATE6CPcAB0HII8CwldeWlwfxgwO4QA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract nested conditional type to generic type:

```
type IdentityRefsCommon = { refs: any[] };

type EntityWithIdentity<E extends IdentityRefsCommon, I> = I extends E['refs'][number] ? E : never;

type ImplementsThree<E extends IdentityRefsCommon> = E extends any ? EntityWithIdentity<E, { identity: typeof three }> : never;


const Bar: ImplementsThree<HasRefs<Entities>> = {
    id: 1,
    refs: [{
        identity: "one",
    }, {
        identity: "two",
    }, {
        identity: "three",
    }]
} // Now it only Bar
```